# (Sans serif) math font that goes well with Montserrat Light as regular text font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, sans-serif

I want to use *Montserrat Light* as the main font for my document and its *semibold* version to render LaTeX bold. According to https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/montserratlight/ and http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/montserrat/doc/montserrat-doc.pdf, all I have to do is install the package and start my document like this:

```
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,semibold,tabular,lining]{montserrat} %% Option 'defaultfam'
%% only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}
```

MY QUESTION: **Can you suggest an appropriate math font (probably bettter a sans-serif one) to combine with Montserrat, and provide the code to make it all work?**

Montserrat is described as

> a geometric sans-serif typeface [...] rather close in spirit to Gotham and Proxima Nova, but has its own individual appearance — more informal, less extended, and more idiosyncratic.

(https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/montserrat/)

See a sample for Montserrat Light in the picture below:

[image: Montserrat Light sample]

Actually, **what happens if I simply add the code above (for Montserrat) and type some equations? Will they be rendered with the default sans-serif math font, if that is a thing?**

Some packages that may help, but not sure:

- `sansmath` - https://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath
- `sfmath` with `sansmathaccent` - https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sfmath, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sansmathaccent
- `mathastext` - https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext

So, I can try those, but I would also like to learn from your previous experience and expertise.

Comment: I think first loading `cmbright` or maybe `lxfonts`, then `montserrat` (to overrule outside math), and then `mathastext` (with or without the `italic` option) is another possibility; looks passable to me.

Comment: Are you able to use `unicode-math`?